# QML ListView focus on first item except header delegate

Tags: qt, scroll, qml, scrollview, qtquick2

I use QML `ScrollView` and `ListView`. `ListView` consists of `headerDelegate` and `delegate`:

```
ScrollView {
    id: scrollView
    Layout.fillWidth: true
    Layout.fillHeight: true
    width: parent.width
    height: parent.height
    ListView{
        id: listView
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
        spacing: 10
        header: headerDelegate
        anchors.fill: parent
        property bool isFolded: false
        model: MyModel
        delegate: mainDelegate
    }
}
```

Everytime `ListView` is scrolled to the top the first `mainDelegate` is shown instead of `headerDelegate` which remains hidden. How can I force the scroll to correctly show `headerDelegate`?

Comment: I do not understand what is the problem.

Comment: When ListView appear, I can see first item, not header data. For seeing header data I have to scroll down and up, after this manipulation I can see header data

Comment: You should provide fully working code, not just pieces. Also consider to avoid setting sizes if you `anchor.fill` an element. Using basic `Rectangle`s in place of your delegates results in a correctly working code.

Comment: @BaCaRoZzo I thought the same it is working fine but isn't the scrollbar wrongly positioned for you? It was for me, as I described it in my answer.

Comment: @FilipHazubski Seems fine to me, i.e. completely to the top when the header is shown (Qt 5.6). That's why I pray people for full working code. :(

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that `ScrollView` expects child's `contentY` to be equal `0` but `ListView` positions the first item of the model at `contentY = 0` and places header item before it. If `ListView.header` is `50px` high then it is positioned at `ListView.contentY = -50`.

The solution that worked for me was to emit `ListView.contentYChanged()` signal. It causes `ScrollView` to update. Let me know if this solves your issue.

```
ScrollView {
    id: scrollView
    Layout.fillWidth: true
    Layout.fillHeight: true
    width: parent.width
    height: parent.height
    ListView{
        id: listView
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
        spacing: 10
        header: headerDelegate
        anchors.fill: parent
        property bool isFolded: false
        model: listModel
        delegate: mainDelegate
        onContentYChanged: console.log(contentY)
        Component.onCompleted: {
            contentYChanged()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope, it does not work. After loading ListView I've got Y position "0" and Header is now showed only after scrolling, Y position is changed to -400 (possibly header's height)

Comment: I've changed listView.contentY manually. After finally loading header (I got event) I've set listView.contentY = 0 - headerDelegateView.height and it works. @Filip Hazubski thank you for good way of solution!

Comment: example code
'Rectangle'
{
    id: headerDelegateView
    WebEngineView{
    ...
    onLoadingChanged: {
    if (loadRequest.status === WebEngineView.LoadSucceededStatus) {
    ... // here I calculate web page height by java script and set to headerDelegateView.height
    listView.contentY = 0 - headerDelegateView.height
    }
ScrollView {
 ...
    ListView{
        id: listView
       ...
        }
    }
}'

Answer (score 1):

I've changed listView.contentY manually. After finally loading header (I got event) I've set listView.contentY = 0 - headerDelegateView.height and it works. @Filip Hazubski thank you for good way of solution!

example code

```
Rectangle
{
id: headerDelegateView
WebEngineView{
...
onLoadingChanged: {
if (loadRequest.status === WebEngineView.LoadSucceededStatus) {
... // here I calculate web page height by java script and set to headerDelegateView.height
listView.contentY = 0 - headerDelegateView.height
}
ScrollView {
...
ListView{
    id: listView
   ...
    }
}
}
```